# Lagrange Multiplier Resulting in One Critical Point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Some questions that I do involving Lagrange Multipliers result in only one critical point. What is a consistent method I can use to show the critical point is a max or a min because it cannot be both. I provided examples to show what I am looking for.

> For Example 1: Write the sum of 270 as a sum of 3 numbers so that the
>   sum of products taken 2 at a time is a maximum:
>
> $f(x,y,z) = xy +xz+yz$
>
> $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z = 270$

By LaGrange multipliers, we can easily obtain the point $(90,90,90)$. The question obviously points out that we are looking for a maximum value, but what if we are not told that $(90,90,90)$ is a max? What method do I use to prove it is in fact a maximum?

> For Example 2: Let S be the line in the plane through $(−1, 0)$
>   inclined at 45◦ and let $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ . Find the extrema of
>   f|S and also its extreme values.
>
> $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$
>
> $g(x,y) = y-x = 1$ (the equation of the inclined line)

By LaGrange multipliers, we can easily obtain the critical point $(-1/2, 1/2)$ but is it a max or a min?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know whether Lagrange multipliers gives maximum or minimum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076766/how-to-know-whether-lagrange-multipliers-gives-maximum-or-minimum)

Comment: I was under the assumption that border hessians were only useful for local max/min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one critical point then you can use the [Bordered Hessian technique.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian)